# Extended DataGrid row error

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm getting that error stated in the title when I'm trying to set the row equal to what the user selects. Error happens on this line:

```
DataGridRow row = e.Row as DataGridRow;
```

> Error Message: Cannot convert type
>   'ExtendedGrid.Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow' to
>   'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow' via a reference conversion,
>   boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null
>   type conversion

I'm using the WPF Extended DataGrid. Here's the source code for the RowDetailsVisibilityChanged event:

```
private void RowDetailsVisibilityChanged(object sender, ExtendedGrid.Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs e)
{
        DataGridRow row = e.Row as DataGridRow;
        FrameworkElement tb = GetTemplateChildByName(row, "RowHeaderToggleButton");
        if (tb != null)
        {
            if (row.DetailsVisibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
            {
                (tb as ToggleButton).IsChecked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                (tb as ToggleButton).IsChecked = false;
            }
        }

 }
```

Any suggestions on what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `e.Row` is not a `System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow`. The creators of the WPF Extended DataGrid must have created their own `DataGridRow` class.

You'll need to cast to the correct type:

```
var row = e.Row as ExtendedGrid.Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow;
```

You may also need to adjust the rest of your code, depending on what information is actually available in the `ExtendedGrid.Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow` class.